# how can I modify the focus on content button in my own template (SP 2013)?

Tags: 2013, site-template

I'm currently creating a own template for my page. I can't figure out how the **focus on content button** works:
[image]

If I past in the following snippet from the *seatle.html* template the focus on content button works with this snippet. It seems to me it is associated with the given id `sideNavBox`, because if I remove it, it won't work any more.

```
<div id="sideNavBox" class="ms-dialogHidden ms-forceWrap ms-noList">
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-core-navigation" role="navigation" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server">-->
<a id="startNavigation" name="startNavigation" tabIndex="-1">
</a>
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarTop" runat="server"/>-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchTop" runat="server"/>-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarDataSource" runat="server"/>-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator" runat="server"/>-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftActions" runat="server"/>-->
<div class="ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin">
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:SPNavigationManager
        id="QuickLaunchNavigationManager"
        runat="server" 
        QuickLaunchControlId="V4QuickLaunchMenu"
        ContainedControl="QuickLaunch"
        EnableViewState="false">-->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" 
        ControlId="QuickLaunchDataSource">-->
    <!--SPM:<Template_Controls>-->
    <!--SPM:<asp:SiteMapDataSource 
        SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" 
        ShowStartingNode="False"
        id="QuickLaunchSiteMap" 
        StartingNodeUrl="sid:1025" 
        runat="server"/>-->
    <!--SPM:</Template_Controls>-->
    <!--SPM:</SharePoint:DelegateControl>-->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:AspMenu
        id="V4QuickLaunchMenu"
        runat="server"
        EnableViewState="false" 
        DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap"
        UseSimpleRendering="true"
        Orientation="Vertical"
        StaticDisplayLevels="3"
        AdjustForShowStartingNode="true"
        MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0"
        SkipLinkText=""/>-->
    <!--SPM:</SharePoint:SPNavigationManager>-->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:SPNavigationManager
        id="TreeViewNavigationManagerV4"
        runat="server" 
        ContainedControl="TreeView"
        CssClass="ms-tv-box">-->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx" id="idNavLinkSiteHierarchyV4" Text="&#60;%$Resources:wss,treeview_header%&#62;" accesskey="&#60;%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%&#62;" 
        CssClass="ms-tv-header"/>-->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TreeViewAndDataSource">-->
    <!--SPM:<Template_Controls>-->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:SPHierarchyDataSourceControl
            runat="server"
            id="TreeViewDataSourceV4"
            RootContextObject="Web"
            IncludeDiscussionFolders="true"/>-->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:SPRememberScroll runat="server" id="TreeViewRememberScrollV4" onscroll="javascript:_spRecordScrollPositions(this);" 
            style="overflow: auto;">-->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:SPTreeView
            id="WebTreeViewV4"
            runat="server"
            ShowLines="false"
            DataSourceId="TreeViewDataSourceV4"
            ExpandDepth="0"
            SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="ms-tv-selected"
            NodeStyle-CssClass="ms-tv-item"
            SkipLinkText=""
            NodeIndent="12"
            ExpandImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/tvclosed.png?rev=23"
            ExpandImageUrlRtl="/_layouts/15/images/tvclosedrtl.png?rev=23"
            CollapseImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/tvopen.png?rev=23"
            CollapseImageUrlRtl="/_layouts/15/images/tvopenrtl.png?rev=23"
            NoExpandImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/tvblank.gif?rev=23">-->
    <!--SPM:</SharePoint:SPTreeView>-->
    <!--SPM:</SharePoint:SPRememberScroll>-->
    <!--SPM:</Template_Controls>-->
    <!--SPM:</SharePoint:DelegateControl>-->
    <!--SPM:</SharePoint:SPNavigationManager>-->
    <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom" runat="server">-->
    <div class="ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox">
        <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ClusteredSPLinkButton
        runat="server"
        id="idNavLinkViewAll"
        PermissionsString="ViewFormPages"
        NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx"
        Text="&#60;%$Resources:wss,AllSiteContentMore%&#62;"
        accesskey="&#60;%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%&#62;"
        CssClass="ms-core-listMenu-item ms-core-listMenu-heading"/>-->
        <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><a id="ctl00_idNavLinkViewAll" accesskey="3" class="ms-core-listMenu-item ms-core-listMenu-heading" href="#"><span class="ms-splinkbutton-text">All Site Content</span></a><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
    </div>
    <!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
</div>
<!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```

How can I assign content collapse on any html-element in my template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The focus on content method does two things: 1) it adds a cookie so that it knows to repeat the behavior when the page is loaded again, and 2) it adds a css class to the body: ms-fullscreenmode.

If you need to use that you can do CSS targeting to apply styles to your content.  For instance:

```
.ms-fullscreenmode .myClassThatIsInsideTheBodyTag { display: none; }
```

In the above example, the myClassThatIsInsideTheBodyTag CSS only gets applied when inside an element with the ms-fullscreenmode class.